# Memory growth during Opencv preprocessing for Tensorflow learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

Using tensorflow to learn image models.

The image is read in opencv and nomalized from 0 to 1.

But the memory is going to grow a lot.

What's the reason?

```
def create_dataset(img_folder):
    img_data_array=[]
    class_name=[]

    for path in os.listdir(img_folder):
        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(img_folder, path)):
                continue

            image_path = os.path.join(img_folder, path,  file)

            image = cv2.imread( image_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            image = cv2.resize(image, (HEIGHT, WIDTH),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

            image = np.array(image)
            
            image = image.astype('float') / 255 # <-- Here
         
            img_data_array.append(image)
            class_name.append(path)

    return img_data_array, class_name
```

> image = image.astype('float') / 255

I used too much memory in this part.

Comment: You can try to save memory by avoiding creating a new tensor for the division operation:
```
image /= 255
image = image.astype('float')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory increases because you're adding numpy arrays to a list in every iteration.

Depending on the size of your dataset, it is possible that you may not be able to load the complete dataset in ram. This issue is usually mitigated using a loader. For pytorch there are [dataloaders](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) and for tensorflow there is [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

For this specific resizing operation it is probably better (and conventional) to output these resized images to a directory, and read the images in batches as needed.

The reason you run out of memory during image.astype('float') / 255 is because you go from uint8 to float32, increasing the memory usage by 4x for that resized image.